# How to get 'specific' keys with maximum value in dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

My dict is:

```
rec_Dict = {'000000000500test.0010': -103,
            '000000000500test.0012': -104,
            '000000000501test.0015': -105,
            '000000000501test.0017': -106}
```

I know how to find maximum value:

```
>>print 'max:' + str(max(recB_Dict.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)))
max:(u'000000000500test.0010', -103)`
```

But I want to find keys beginning with `'000000000501test'`, but not including `'000000000501test.0015'` or any starting with `'000000000500test'`.

It should print like:

```
max:(u'000000000501test.0015', -105)`
```

How can I use keyword to get?

Comment: Are you looking to exclude the *exact* match of '.0015' and '000000000500test'? or is there a specific general pattern you are looking to ignore?

Comment: Because I will have '000000000501test.0015','000000000501test.0017','000000000501test.0019' or more , I just want compare same begin like '000000000501test' or '000000000500test' not include '0015','0017'...thanks for your help

Comment: If you don't want to include `'000000000501test.0015'`, as you say, why should it be the one printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't understand the conditions you want to filter keys, but you can use the below scripts (just fix the conditions)

```
genetator_filter = genetator_filter = ((a,b) for a,b in rec_Dict.iteritems() if (not '.0015' in a) and (not '000000000500test.' in a) )
#(you need to fix filter conditions for keys)

print 'max:' + str(max(genetator_filter, key = lambda x:x[1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Separating responsibility to achieve the final result, you can find your max based on what you are looking to match on exactly. Then using that max, just output the value. Granted, some will argue that it is not *the most optimized*, or not the most *functional* way to go about it. But, personally, it works just fine, and achieves the result with good enough performance. Furthermore, makes it more readable and easy to test.

#### Get the max based on the part of the string you want by extracting keys and finding the max:

```
max_key_substr = max(i.split('.')[0] for i in rec_Dict)
```

#### Iterate with that `max_key_substr` and output the key/value pair:

```
for key, value in rec_Dict.items():
    if max_key_substr in key:
        print(key, value)
```

The output will be:

```
000000000501test.0015 -105
000000000501test.0017 -106
```

Answer (score 1):

What you say it should print like doesn't make sense because the key `'000000000501test.0015'`should have been excluded according to other things you said.

Ignoring that, you could use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html?#generator-expressions) to sift-out the items you don't want processed:

```
from operator import itemgetter

rec_Dict = {'000000000500test.0010': -103,
            '000000000500test.0012': -104,
            '000000000501test.0015': -105,
            '000000000501test.0017': -106}

def get_max(items):
    def sift(record):
        key, value = record
        return key.startswith('000000000501') and not key.endswith('.0015')

    max_record = max((item for item in items if sift(item)), key=itemgetter(1))
    return max_record

print(get_max(rec_Dict.iteritems()))  # -> ('000000000501test.0017', -106)
```